# How do I discover an trust fund, or estate account, that is being hidden by a malfeasant executor?

Tags: fraud, civil-rights

I have documents indicating there is an estate account being held under a minority heirs name & SSN, but the bank agents refuses to answer any questions about the account!  No local attorney will touch the case because of the bank involved is the largest bank in the state and extremely well connected politically!

Comment: What’s your standing here? Are you the minor or their guardian?

Comment: "No local attorney will touch the case because of the bank involved is the largest bank in the state and extremely well connected politically!" This is bullshit. There is no place with four or more lawyers where some lawyer wouldn't be willing to take on a case like this one. Making a legal inquiry about fiduciary accounts is not something that a bank takes as an affront in the way suggested. You are vastly misunderstanding the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately you underestimate the injustice that goes on in the South. Take an actual look at the case and then tell me how it is being misunderstood. Enter “thecoldcase.org” into your browser. Attorneys have been retained in regards to the family’s property issues, and the federal courts have refused to grant injunctive relief, despite clear evidence the account exists!!

Comment: Status: Next Friend to heir unable to get any relief himself

Comment: Looking for constructive advice here, not crass remarks!

Comment: The person I am helping took the documents to the bank, and the bank president told him “those documents are no good”, denied the account existed, and then had him arrested.  I would call that an “affront”, wouldn’t you?

Comment: If the Minority Heir has been arrested then s/he can use the documents indicating the account exists in their defence at trial to show that they were making a reasonable request of the bank. Then the truth (one way or another) should come out.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't give legal advice here, which appears to be what you are looking for.  If no local attorney will touch it, you may want to look at attorneys outside of the local area.

Comment: Rick, I appreciate your suggestions, & they are meaningful in a perfect world, unfortunately we are not fighting this case in a state where the law actually means anything if you are a poor black defendant, or black family fighting against a white run judicial system. It took the federal court 2 years to actually acknowledge that the documents support our claim that there is a dispute over an account, yet they deny any injunctions or attempt at discovery to gain access to it so as to retain counsel!  Look at the documents yourself  <http://thecoldcase.org> & then tell me what they mean!

Comment: Ryan,  not seeking legal advice, just  trying to engage in an academic discussion of real world legal problems.  There was a time that I really believed that judges were neutral arbiters of the law, but then you come across a case like this & realize all is not well in ‘Mudville!’  We have gone to out of state firms, & no one wants to take on the “State of Alabama” or the banks involved, & return the retainers!  Even the usual civil rights organizations acknowledge the “difficult situation” but refuse to help. Academic discussions are fine —  if they prepare you for the real world!